# How to chain multiple JS promises to combined boolean result

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying validate a variety of elements and their data on my page. I have 3 different methods to complete the validation, some of which make ajax calls. Each one returns a promise of a boolean. I want to combine the results into one variable. I thought the following code was working correctly, but my `isValid` variable seems to only be capturing the value of the last validation function called, `saveCurrentSource()`. How do I get `isValid` to be equal to the results of `saveSourceResponse()` && `validateSource()` && `saveCurrentSource()`?

```
async validate() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let isValid = this.saveSourceResponse()
      .then(saveSourceResponse => {
      console.log("saveSourceResponse",saveSourceResponse);
        return this.validateSource();
      }).then(validateSourceResponse => {
          console.log("validateSourceResponse",validateSourceResponse);
        return this.saveCurrentSource(validateSourceResponse);
      }).then(saveCurrentSourceResponse => {
          console.log("saveCurrentSourceResponse",saveCurrentSourceResponse);
        return saveCurrentSourceResponse;
      });
    resolve(isValid);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you're using an `async` method, there's no need for directly accessing the promises at all, just use `await`:

```
async validate() {
    return (
        await this.saveSourceResponse() &&
        await this.validateSource() &&
        await this.saveCurrentSource()
    );
}
```

(I've also added a parallel version below.)

*(I'm assuming `saveCurrentSource` doesn't actually need the argument you're passing to it.)*

If you **did** want to access the promises (e.g., not use `async` on `validate`), you'd use `&&` in each `then` handler — and wouldn't use `new Promise`, as there's no reason to:

```
validate() {
    return this.saveSourceResponse()
        .then(isValid => isValid && this.validateSource())
        .then(isValid => isValid && this.saveCurrentSource());
}
```

---

If my assumption about `saveCurrentSource` is incorrect, we'd adjust those accordingly:

```
async validate() {
    return (
        await this.saveSourceResponse() &&
        await this.validateSource() &&
        await this.saveCurrentSource(true) // `true` because this won't get executed
                                           // if `this.validateSource()` resolves
                                           // to `false`
    );
}
```

Or:

```
validate() {
    return this.saveSourceResponse()
        .then(isValid => isValid && this.validateSource())
        .then(isValid => isValid && this.saveCurrentSource(true)); // `true` again,
                                                                   // see above
}
```

---

As [Sescudero points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674504/how-to-chain-multiple-js-promises-to-combined-boolean-result/51674618#comment90312274_51674588), if those *can* run in parallel, we should run them in parallel:

```
async validate() {
    const results = await Promise.all([
        this.saveSourceResponse(),
        this.validateSource(),
        this.saveCurrentSource()
    ]);
    return results.every(valid => valid);
}
```

...which is very much the same if not using `async`:

```
validate() {
    return Promise.all([
        this.saveSourceResponse(),
        this.validateSource(),
        this.saveCurrentSource()
    ]).then(results => results.every(valid => valid));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last `then` is returning `saveCurrentSourceResponse`. You need it to return all the other returned responses, too, perhaps by storing them in a local variable like so:

```
async validate() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let responses = [];
    let isValid = this.saveSourceResponse()
      .then(saveSourceResponse => {
        responses.push({saveSourceResponse});
      console.log("saveSourceResponse",saveSourceResponse);
        return this.validateSource();
      }).then(validateSourceResponse => {
        responses.push({validateSourceResponse});
          console.log("validateSourceResponse",validateSourceResponse);
        return this.saveCurrentSource(validateSourceResponse);
      }).then(saveCurrentSourceResponse => {
        responses.push({saveCurrentSourceResponse});
          console.log("saveCurrentSourceResponse",saveCurrentSourceResponse);
        return responses;
      });
    resolve(isValid);
  });
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `new Promise` in an `async` method, or indeed when you already have promises to work with (even in a non-`async` method).

Comment: Nice, but you can combine some of them to call them in parallel